# Stored Tfidf-Vectorizer ValueError when loaded again

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I trained a Tfidf-Vectorizer for a PassiveAgressive Classifier and tested it, everything works just fine. Then I saved the fitted vectorizer and the trained classifier for later use. When I loaded the vectorizer again, I transformed a new dataset on it (as I want to classify unseen data with the classifier) and tried to predict the new dataset. When I run the code, I get:

```
ValueError: X has 1375913 features per sample; expecting 1373084
```

This is the code I used to get the vectorizer and classifier:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Processed_text'], y, test_size=0.2)
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_train = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
with open('vectorizer.pkl', 'wb') as fin:
    pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, fin)
tfidf_test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_test)
linear_clf = PassiveAggressiveClassifier(n_iter=50)
linear_clf.fit(tfidf_train, y_train)
pred = linear_clf.predict(tfidf_test)
with open('topic_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(linear_clf, fid)
```

And this is how I open it again and use it:

```
classifier = pickle.load(open('topic_classifier.pkl', 'rb'))
vectorizer = pickle.load(open('vectorizer.pkl', 'rb'))
tfidf_vectorizer = vectorizer
tfidf_articles = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(texts)
topics = classifier.predict(tfidf_articles)
```

I also checked again in the file where I trained the classifier and looked at the length of the vocabulary and got

```
len(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
1371569
```

So yet another number... I really do not know what is going wrong here. I processed the texts for the train/test datasets and the texts that need to be classified after loading everything again exactly the same way, so I do not think this is related to the input I am giving to the vectorizer. I cannot fit the vectorizer again or train the classifier again as I am using both in an app - so it needs to work somehow with the saved versions.

Answer (score 0):

After checking everything again and again it turned out that there is some issue with saving vectorizers and classifiers with pickle.dump. When I used joblib.dump/load for both, it worked like a charm! Apparently not a good idea to use pickle for data persistence here!